# I want to access current user in controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have logged in using passport and API, now I want to access current user in web route. How can I get user details in a controller?

```
auth('api')->user();
```

Comment: What is the error now?

Comment: it return null.

Comment: Which laravel version are you using?

Comment: using laravel 5.7

Comment: Can you show your web route file?

Comment: Route::resource('/posts', 'Blog\PostController');
I have logged in with passport token api. Here need authenticated user id.

Answer (score 0):

Will you please try this?

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->user =  \Auth::user();
    }
```